# Logging response headers in Apache reverse proxy without sending them to the client

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, http-headers

We use serveral Apache servers as reverse proxy in front of numerous backend servers. The backend servers send a HTTP response header ("Cast") which contains an internal name of the backend server.

In the reverse proxy I would like to log the content of the backend server's response header and prevent the header from being sent to the client.

Logging the header is simple with inserting `%{Cast}o` in our custom `LogFormat` configuration. 
Also, preventing the header from being sent to the client is easy, by using `Header unset Cast`

The only problem is that when unsetting the header it cannot be logged anymore.

Is there a way to store the backend's response header in a variable, unset the header and log the variable?

**Notes**

- The Apache servers being used as reverse proxies are Apache 2.2 on RHEL 6 and 2.4 on RHEL7
- Reverse proxy rules use either `ProxyPass`or `RewriteRule ... [P]`

Comment: As the log module works last, unseting the header removes the data. Only way I can think of is storing that info into a variable and logging that instead. Since SetEnvIf does not work on response headers, only way I can think of is or by a second proxy in between (as sugested by HBruijn) or by a custom module to read the header and create the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used a intermediate VirtualHost entry as a work-around for similar situations when certain directives didn't play well together:

Your current configuration may look like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   ProxyPass /app http://app.example.com/app
   ProxyPassReverse /app http://app.example.com/app
</VirtualHost>
```

Modify that to point to the intermediate virtual host and strip your header from the responses:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8000/app
   ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8000/app
   Header unset Cast
</VirtualHost>
```

and a new virtual host where you can still log your Cast headers:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8000
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8000>
   ServerName localhost
   ProxyPass /app http://app.example.com/app
   ProxyPassReverse /app http://app.example.com/appp
   LogFormat %{X-Forwarded-For}o %{Cast}o ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I considered something similar, but in a working enviroment with 30+ Virtualhosts with many reverseproxy rules this would get very complex quickly. Furthermore, the reverse proxy has considerable traffic, I fear that this would add to load and latency.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit that it is not a very pretty work-around. Nothing better comes to mind though. In general:  If your current solution doesn't meet your requirements, either change your requirements, or change your solution. Common high-performance reverse proxy alternatives to Apache are for instance HAProxy and Varnish or commercial solutions  such as F5 Big-IP (which we currently use and are in general quite pleased with) and Bluecoat.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Changing the reverse proxy is not a (short term) option. Before dropping the requirement, I think I am going to look if there is an optional Apache module, which can help me accomplish the task one way or the other.